# SSL certificates in Plesk

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, plesk

There seems to be two places in PLESK to add SSL certificates. One location is under Domains 
[image]

and another under Tools and Settings.
[image]

What is the purpose of the first versus the second location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both locations in PLESK (v12) accomplish the exact same thing. The one added benefit to adding the SSL under the domain name is accessing the IP address via HTTPS (answer from hosting company).

I hope it helps someone in the future.